# Can someone explain these errors to me? It says invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int'). I want to calculate roots of a quadratic equation

Tags: c

I am learning C and I had to create a program that calculates the roots of a quadratic equation. I have written a code that can take the whole quadratic equation as input from the user and then assign it to variables. but when I am using the switch statement it is showing an error. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main()
{
    char a[20];
    char firstOperand;
    char b[20];
    char secondOperand;
    char c[20];
    char thirdOperand = '=';
    char d = '0';
    int a1;
    int b1;
    int c1;
    int d1;
    int D;
    int x1;

    printf("Please enter the quadratic equation: ");
    scanf("%s %c %s %c %s", a, &firstOperand, b, &secondOperand, c);

    a1 = atoi(a);
    b1 = atoi(b);
    c1 = atoi(c);

    printf("%d %d %d", a1, b1, c1);
    switch(-b1 + sqrt((b1**2) - (4*a1*c1))/ (2*a1))
           {
          case 1:
              x1 = (-b1 + sqrt((b1**2) - (4*a1*c1))/ (2*a1));
              printf("The first root of the quadratic equation is: %d", x1);
              break;
           }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]
These are the errors I am getting. Also note that I just started learning c programming

Comment: `**` is not a valid operator in C. Use `b1 * b1` instead.

Comment: Please note that `#include <math.h>` is missing and that `sqrt` returns a floating point value. Are you trying to do all the calculations using integer arithmetic (the divisions in particular)? How do you expect that `switch` to work?

Comment: Bobs comment indicates you do not have warnings of your compiler turned on: turn them on!

Comment: The result of the switch expression is questionable (in several ways). Aside from the purpose, the eg division with `ints` will not produce reliable calculation results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you have several problems.

First, `**` is not a valid operator in C. `b1**2` is being interpreted as `b1 * (*2)` - the compiler thinks you’re treating `2` as a pointer and trying to dereference it.  Since `2` is an `int` and not a pointer type, the compiler is complaining.

C does not have an exponent operator - you either have to do the multiplication manually (`b1*b1`) or you have to use the `pow` function (`pow( b1, 2 )`).

Secondly, you need to `#include <math.h>` for `sqrt` (and `pow` and trig functions and other math functions).

Finally, `switch` operates on integer expressions, but the presence of `sqrt` in the expression guarantees a floating point result.  It’s not even clear to me *why* you are using the `switch`.  What are you trying to do there?

Also, integer division yields an integer result - `1/2 == 0`, `3/2 == 1`, `5/2 == 2`, etc.  `(4*a1*c1) / (2*a1)` may not give you the result you expect.  You might want to declare your variables as `double` rather than `int` (meaning you’ll need to use `%lf` instead of `%d` in the `scanf` calls).